# What are the conditional jump instructions for Go's assembler?

Tags: assembly, go

Go's 6a assembler has conditional jump instructions:

```
JCC
JCS
JCXZL
JEQ
JGE
JGT
JHI
JLE
JLS
JLT
JMI
JNE
JOC
JOS
JPC
JPL
JPS
```

But how do they map to x86 conditional jumps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm answering this so I don't lose the information, and so other people don't have to go through the same sleuthing game as me. Looking at [optab.c](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/cmd/8l/optab.c?spec=svn40dd722155f6d0c83fa572c1a5abf7c6ff35049f&r=0c67faa66be793b487192717a827c5412dd794bf) and the [x86 jumps](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html) we can match up the instruction encodings to solve the puzzle.

```
JCC     JAE
JCS     JB
JCXZL   JECXZ
JEQ     JE,JZ
JGE     JGE
JGT     JG
JHI     JA
JLE     JLE
JLS     JBE
JLT     JL
JMI     JS
JNE     JNE, JNZ
JOC     JNO
JOS     JO
JPC     JNP, JPO
JPL     JNS
JPS     JP, JPE
```

Comment: The same suffixes are used, with the same meanings, for SETxx and CMOVxx as well.

Answer (score 2):

The Go assembler's [arch.go](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/master/src/cmd/asm/internal/arch/arch.go#115) says:

```
instructions["JA"]  = x86.AJHI
instructions["JAE"] = x86.AJCC
instructions["JB"]  = x86.AJCS
etc
```

which means that Go asm's JHI means Intel asm's JA, etc.